# For what n the following inequality holds?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I reformulated the question by entering my demonstration attempt

$$\prod_{2\lt p \le\sqrt 2n}\left(\frac{p-1}{p-2}\right)^2\le\frac n2$$

I tried to prove it this way: Let n be an integer, p be a prime. We have a chain of equivalences: $$\prod_{i=2}^{\pi(\sqrt 2n)}\left(\frac{pi-1}{pi-2}\right)^2\le\frac n2$$      $$\prod_{i=2}^k\left(\frac{pi-1}{pi-2}\right)^2\le\frac n2$$ , for $$ \pi(\sqrt 2n)=k $$ But it is an easy task to prove $$ 2 \phi(\theta_{k}) \lt P_{k} \prod_{i=2}^k(Pi-2)$$  $$\prod_{2\lt p \le\sqrt 2n}\left(\frac{p-1}{p-2}\right)^2\le\frac n2$$  where $\theta k$=3 . 5 .7 ....P_{k}

Indreed $$4 \phi^2(\theta_{k})\lt Pk^2 \prod_{i=2}^k(Pi-2)^2$$ $$ 2\phi(\theta k)\lt P_{k} \prod_{i=2}^k(Pi-2)$$

Our next task is to prove that $$ 2\phi(\theta_{k})\lt \phi $$ $$\phi\lt P_{k} \psi_{k} $$ wher $$\psi_{k} = \prod_{i=2}^k(Pi-2)$$ By inspection we can verify that for $$K \le 4$$ $$ 2\phi(\theta_{k})\lt \theta_{k} $$ We have left out to prove that $$K \le 4$$ $$\theta \lt P_{k} \psi $$  Assume at the contrary that $$ P_{k} \psi _{k}\le\theta _{k}$$  We have $$ P_{k} \psi_{k}\le\theta_{k}$$ $$\psi_{k} \le \theta_{k-1} $$ 
$$ \prod_{i=2}^k(Pi-2) \lt 3 .5 .7 ....P_{k}-1$$

Now it is clair that the last relation is patently false..

According to you is correct?

Thank's

Comment: $0 \le \left(\frac{p-1}{p-2}\right) <1$ for $p\ge 1$ so $\prod\limits_{2\lt p \le\sqrt 2n}\left(\frac{p-1}{p-2}\right)^2\lt 1 \le \frac n2$ for $n\ge 2$